# Implementation of binary search in java

Tags: java, binary-search

I'm trying to implement binary search in Java. I'm working with an array of prime numbers up to 100. Here's the code:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        binarySearch(new int[]{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97}, 29, 0, 24);
    }

    public static int binarySearch(int[] sortedArray, int key, int min, int max) {
        int average = (min + max) / 2;

        if (Arrays.asList(sortedArray).contains(key)) {
            if (average == key) {
                System.out.println("You have guessed the right number and it is: " + average);
                return average;
            } else if (key > average) {
                System.out.println("Key is greater than average, going back to loop: " + average);
                return binarySearch(sortedArray, key, average + 1, max);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Key is smaller than average, going back to loop : " + average);
                return binarySearch(sortedArray, key, min, average - 1);
            }
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

I think that probably there's a problem with the call of `binarySearch` in `main`, but I'm not sure in what way I can implement it.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're facing?

Comment: That doesn't look like a binary search algorithm to me. It's close, but not quite there. Where did you get `Arrays.asList(sortedArray).contains(key)`? And you're supposed to be testing the value at the midpoint between `min` and `max` (the element at the `average` index, in your code—a better name for `average` would be e.g. `mid` in my opinion). Currently you're testing the index against `key`, not the element-at-index against `key`.

Comment: I used Arrays.asList(...) to check whether the array contains the given prime, if not return -1

Comment: Another additional question, is the array of primes correctly declared or should I declare it some other way?

Comment: Also additionally, is the recursive implementation the best way to tackle this search or not really?

Comment: @stafino You don't need to check if the array contains the given prime, that should be handled by the solution itself. Your recursive implementation is the right approach, but there should be a base case that stops the recursion once the average is equal to min or max.

Comment: @MAnouti isn't that the if (sortedArray[mid] == key) { part?

Comment: Yes it should be, just make sure your solution works also for cases where the key does not exist in the list.

Comment: First, the `sortedArray` is the _same_ array throughout the operation so your `contains` code will return the same value every time. Second, the entire purpose of the `binarySearch` method you're writing is to test if the element is in the array using the binary search algorithm—calling `contains` is in opposition to that purpose. Once you've reached the `max < min` case you know the element is not in the array and the result is `-1`. And your array declaration is fine, at least for your use case.

Comment: And I should clarify, the "entire purpose" is what I described before but also to return the index of the element in the array if present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main issues in your code (you could have easily figured them out if you ran the code with a debugger):

1. `if (Arrays.asList(sortedArray).contains(key)) {`

   Why do you need this? The whole purpose of this method is to search for the key, so you shouldn't invoke this code. And besides, this code does not work because `Arrays.asList(sortedArray)` would return a `List<int[]>`, **NOT** a `List<int>`, which will never contain the key, so this expression will always return false.
2. You're comparing the key to an index in the list, you should compare it against the *element* at the index:

   ```
    if (sortedArray[average] == key) {
   ```

   also

   ```
    } else if (key > sortedArray[average]) {
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the implementation in
java.util.Collections#binarySearch(java.util.List<? extends java.lang.Comparable<? super T>>, T)